# can't install laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using php 8, and I install laravel 8 using composer to install, I get this error, please tell me how to fix it, 2 images below are the error I am getting. thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kkmj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru7Jy.png)

Comment: Enable the mentioned extensions or installed them.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Maybe you can try to do this. Run this command :

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Or

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: This is like sweeping an uncomfortable situation under the rug.

Answer (score 1):

Do not ignore requirements, it might lead to future headaches. Check what php.ini is being used.
run: php --ini and check what file is in use, then you need  to edit that file in order to enable (add) that extension.

1. Open that php.ini on a text editor (running as admin)
2. Under the ExtensionList section add extension=php_fileinfo.dll

   [ExtensionList]

   extension=php_soap.dll

   extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

   extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

   **extension=php_fileinfo.dll**